# Rocket cannot parse JSON

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm having an error when trying to parse JSON with rocket. This is my code:

```rust
extern crate serde;
use rocket::serde::{json::Json, Deserialize};
use serde::Serialize;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
mod eth;
mod rocket_test;

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/task", routes![body])
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Message2 {
    id: usize,
}

#[post("/", format = "json", data = "<message>")]
async fn body(message: Json<Message2>) -> &'static str {
    "Fine"
}
```

And this is my toml file:

```
[dependencies]
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"]}
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
tester = "0.9.0"
tokio = {version = "1", features = ["full"]}

[dependencies.rocket]
features = ["json"]
version = "0.5.0-rc.1"
```

I'm getting this error

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `0x28f12470657`,
 right: `0x28f12470640`', C:\Users\gadum\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\tokio-1.16.0\src\io\util\take.rs:93:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable 
to display a backtrace
   >> Handler body panicked.
```

It's just the same as in the example of JSON parsing. But I have no idea what is going wrong.
I'm sending requests with VSCode Rest client just like this

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/task
content-type: application/json

{
    "id": 10
}
```

Comment: For one, deserializing into `Message2` would expect an `id` field instead of a `status` field. And two, your json is malformed since it has a trailing comma. If you remove that and change the field name, does it work?

Comment: Regardless, that should probably not panic and give you a more sensible error instead. Perhaps someone should file an issue.

Comment: Oh, those were real problems. But I fixed them and I still have the same error. Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like version `1.16.0` of `tokio` has an error: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/4435

Do a `cargo update` and it should update your dependency to `1.16.1`.